# Deconstruct object values into array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extract some values from an object and put them into an array. So far I have this:

```js
let obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  e: 'e'
};
    
let arr = [{a, b, c} = obj];
    
console.log(arr);
```

However, this is returning an array with just one object:

> [ { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e' } ]

My desired output would be:

`['a', 'b', 'c']`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly would you like as a result? `{a, b, c} = obj` just takes the first three values of your array and put them into three new variables, `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: What are you expecting your output to look like? `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: yes thats correct @mhodges

Answer (score 2):

You could take the values of a new object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
let obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e' },
    { a, b, c } = obj,
    arr = Object.values({ a, b, c });

console.log(arr);
```

Or take the wanted keys for a new array.

```js
let obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e' },
    arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(k => obj[k]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: how about `arr = [a,b,c];` over `arr = Object.values({ a, b, c })`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected use below option
Use () around the assignment statement ,as {} is treated as block but not as object literal during destructuring assignment

```js
let obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  e: 'e'
};
//({a, b, c, ...rest} = obj) // to have access of rest of parameters
({a, b, c} = obj)
let arr = [a,b,c];

console.log(arr);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EeBBjQ?editors=1011

Comment: You really don't need the `...rest` do you?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, it is not necessay but to have access of other parameters, i have used rest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inline by using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```js
let obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  e: 'e'
};
    
let arr = ({a, b, c} = obj, [a, b, c]);
    
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This seems to create globals for `a`, `b`, and `c`. Wonder if that's avoidable?

Comment: It is if you first declare the variables and then evaluate the expression. Not as beautiful, but no globals.